# 3DES Decrypt in java a token encrypted in C#

Tags: c#, java, encryption, base64, 3des

I've searched a lot before asking, but none of the ideas I found work in my problem so here's my problem :

1. In C# the code (which I cannot change because it is from another application) for encryption is detailed after.
2. I have to decrypt the encrypted token in Java but nothing works so far, can anyone help ?

For 1. C# code :

```
    static public string Encrypt3DES(string toEncrypt, string SecKey, string IV){
    byte[] keyArray;
    try
    {
        byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);

    MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SecKey));
        hashmd5.Clear();      

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

        tdes.Key = keyArray;      
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        tdes.IV = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(IV);

        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();

        //transform the specified region of bytes array to resultArray
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
    tdes.Clear();

    //Return the encrypted data into unreadable string format
        return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
    }
    catch (Exception e) { return string.Empty; }
    }
```

For 2 Java code that does not work :

```
    public class TripleDesTest {

private KeySpec keySpec;
private SecretKey key;
private IvParameterSpec iv;

public TripleDesTest() {
    String keyString = "THE_KEY";
    String ivString = "THE_IV";

    try {
        final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
        final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(Base64.decodeBase64(keyString.getBytes("UTF-8")));            
        final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
        for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
            keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
        }

        keySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(keyBytes);

        key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede").generateSecret(keySpec);

        iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public String decrypt(String value) {

    try {
        Cipher dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "SunJCE");
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

        if (value == null)
            return null;

        // Decode base64 to get bytes
        byte[] dec = Base64.decodeBase64(value.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        // Decrypt
        byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);

        // Decode using UTF-8
        return new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
    }
```

Comment: You have different padding modes in Java/C#. Are you sure it should be that way?

Comment: I've understood that PKCS7 and PKCS5 are compatible (after some google searches) and PKCS7 does not exists in standard with Java. I've also try to look at the differences with Base64 encode/decode but with no success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to the problem (I finally was able to solve this myself) :

In Java, replace

```
final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(Base64.decodeBase64(keyString.getBytes("UTF-8")));`
```

with :

```
final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(keyString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Because on the C# side, no Base64 is used for the key :

```
keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SecKey));
```